# How to set the registration point of a Bitmap image to the bottom centre?

Tags: java, bitmap, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am trying to set the registration point of an image to the bottom centre so it can rotate around that point. So far my code looks like this:

```
var img = new createjs.Bitmap("img.png");
img.x = 200;
img.y = 180;
img.scaleX = 0.35;
img.scaleY = 0.35;
img.regX = img.width/2;
img.regY = 0;
img.rotation = 15;
canvas.addChild(img);
```

I tried changing the numbers of img.regY but I can't seem to get it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `redBalloon.width`?

The best approach is to wait until the image is loaded, and then use its natural width.

```
img.image.onload = function() {
    img.regX = img.image.naturalWidth;
    img.regY = img.image.naturalHeight;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I forgot to change redBalloon to img